# Accessing the index of a particular cell in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

I  have to write a method "all()" which returns a list of tuples; each tuple will contain the row, column and set relevant to a particular given row and column, when the function meets a 0 in the list. I already have written the "hyp" function which returns the set part I need, eg: Set(1,2). I am using a list of lists:

```
 | 0 | 0 | 9 |
 | 0 | x | 0 |
 | 7 | 0 | 8 |
```

If Set (1,2) are referring to the cell marked as x, all() should return: (1,1, Set(1,2)) where 1,1 are the index of the row and column.
I wrote this method by using zipWithIndex. Is there any simpler way how to access an index as in this case without zipWithIndex? Thanks in advance
Code:

```
 def all(): List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])] = 
 {
  puzzle.list.zipWithIndex flatMap 
  { 
    rowAndIndex =>
    rowAndIndex._1.zipWithIndex.withFilter(_._1 == 0) map 
    { 
      colAndIndex =>
      (rowAndIndex._2, colAndIndex._2,  hyp(rowAndIndex._2, colAndIndex._2)) 
    }
  }
 }
```

The (_._1 == 0 ) is because the function has to return the (Int,Int, Set()) only when it finds a 0 in the grid

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly common to use zipWithIndex.  Can minimise wrestling with Tuples/Pairs through pattern matching vars within the tuple:

```
def all(grid: List[List[Int]]): List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])] =
  grid.zipWithIndex flatMap {case (row, r) =>
    row.zipWithIndex.withFilter(_._1 == 0) map {case (col, c) => (r, c,  hyp(r, c))}
  }
```

Can be converted to a 100% equivalent for-comprehension:

```
def all(grid: List[List[Int]]): List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])] =
  for {(row, r) <- grid.zipWithIndex; 
       (col, c) <- row.zipWithIndex if (col == 0)} yield (r, c,  hyp(r, c))
```

Both of above produce the same compiled code.

Note that your requirement means that all solutions are minimum O(n) = O(r*c) - you must visit each and every cell.  However the overall behaviour of user60561's answer is O(n^2) = O((r*c)^2): for each cell, there's an O(n) lookup in list(x)(y):

```
for{ x <- list.indices
     y <- list(0).indices
     if list(x)(y) == 0 } yield (x, y, hyp(x, y))
```

Here's similar (imperative!) logic, but O(n):

```
var r, c = -1
for{ row <- list; col <- row if col == 0} yield {
  r += 1
  c += 1
  (r, c, hyp(r, c))
}
```

Recursive version (uses results-accumulator to enable tail-recursion):

```
type Grid = List[List[Int]]
type GridHyp = List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])]

def all(grid: Grid): GridHyp = {
  def rowHypIter(row: List[Int], r: Int, c: Int, accum: GridHyp) = row match {
    case Nil => accum
    case col :: othCols => rowHypIter(othCols, r, c + 1, hyp(r, c) :: accum)}
  def gridHypIter(grid: Grid, r: Int, accum: GridHyp) = grid match {
    case Nil => accum
    case row :: othRows => gridHypIter(othRows, r + 1, rowHyp(row, r, 0, accum))}
  gridHypIter(grid, 0, Nil)
}
```

'Monadic' logic (flatmap/map/withFilter OR equivalent for-comprehensions) is often/usually neater than recursion + pattern-matching - evident here.

Comment: For comprehensions aren't loops - they are purely syntactic sugar for flatmap/map/withFilter.  But maybe you can't use them?

Comment: I can't use iteration, I have to use recursion, are for comprehensions good in this case?

Comment: Ok.  But that's a different question than what you asked.  Have added to my A.

Comment: I don't understand it but thanks a lotttt. I will consider your first piece of code, can you explain it? (I.e def all(grid: List[List[Int]]): List[(Int, Int, Set[Int])] =
  grid.zipWithIndex flatMap {case (row, r) =>
    row.zipWithIndex.withFilter(_._1 == 0) map {case (col, c) => (r, c,  hyp(r, c))}
  } )

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is just a classic for loop:

```
for{ x <- list.indices
     y <- list(0).indices
     if list(x)(y) == 0 } yield (x, y, hyp(x, y))
```

It assumes that your second dimension is of an uniform size. With this code, I would also recommend you use an Array or Vector if your grid sizes are larger then 100 or so because list(x)(y) is a O(n) operation.